# SSH port forwarding a UDP port from Windows

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, udp

I discovered the possibility of forwarding ports through SSH after I sticked up with port forwarding which didn't work out because my provider has DS Lite.

Using `ssh -R 8080:localhost:8080 <myremoteserver>` to ssh to my remote debian 9 as an example/test to forward my local little webserver (express and nodejs) remotely to be able to access it targeting the servers ip works just fine, but this was just for testing, as I need to forward a local gameserver (dolphins netpay) using UDP.

I looked up how to tunnel UDP connections and tried [this approach](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html).
Because my local PC is a Windows I used [ncat from Nmap](https://nmap.org/ncat/).

My first approach was this:

```
# on the server
nc -l -p 6117 < /tmp/fifo | nc -u 192.168.178.66 6117 > /tmp/fifo

# locally (using git bash)
./nc -l -u -p 6117 < ./_fifo | ./nc localhost 6117 > ./_fifo
```

My local machine failed to bind to 6117 because the gameserver was already lsitening to it. I made a few changes.

```
# on the server
nc -l -p 6117 < /tmp/fifo | nc -u 192.168.178.66 6118 > /tmp/fifo

# locally (using git bash)
./nc -l -u -p 6118 < ./_fifo | ./nc localhost 6117 > ./_fifo
```

Yet by doing so I'm still not able to connect to it.
I don't have any experience regarding ncat.

My basic plan is to forward a local gameserver which listens for UDP (and TCP too I guess) to my remote server, so others can connect using my remote host domain.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it _have_ to be SSH? Pretty much all layer-3 VPN solutions will work far more reliably than this.

Comment: I sadly couldn't find any resource regarding this. I do own a VPN plan though (perfect-privacy.com) and you can port forward there as well, let me test that. Thanks.

Comment: No, I was not talking about commercial VPN services. (Some of them provide such a feature, but issuing static IP addresses is kind of contrary to a "privacy"-oriented service.) You have a Debian server so you can set up any VPN on it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I found a OpenVPN tutorial for this case, but I currently stopped working on it because I can't even properly forward IPv6 from my machine, which is weird, because IPv6 forwarding should work on DS Lite.